# jQuery append text to an existing with checkbox

Tags: jquery

So I have a checkbox and textarea with the text

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" class="responsive" checked="checked"> Responsive?<br />
<textarea cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_code; ?>" id="input-code" class="form-control afftextie"><div class="intrinsic-container"><iframe src="content.php" style="overflow: hidden;border:none;width:1000px;height:400px" scrolling="no""></iframe></div></textarea>
```

Now I'm trying to append and extra text/code when checkbox clicked and remove when unchecked.

```
var $input = $( '.afftextie' ).text();
$( ".responsive" ).change(function() {  
$( '.afftextie' ).appennd($input+'<style>.intrinsic-container{position:relative;overflow:hidden;min-height:400px;margin-bottom:10px}.intrinsic-container iframe{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;border:none}@media (max-width:990px){.intrinsic-container{min-height:1151px}}@media (max-width:510px){.intrinsic-container{min-height:1570px}}</style>').text()}).change();
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/wr39vhjt/2/

Comment: `appennd` is not a function

Comment: `scrolling="no""` is invalid markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit your fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ebilgin/wr39vhjt/3/

You must change your code a little bit. First you can reach `textarea`'s inside with `.val()` not `.append()`. Then you need a checked condition.

```
var $input = $( '.afftextie' ).text();
$( ".responsive" ).change(function() {

    if ( $(this).prop("checked") ) {

        $( '.afftextie' ).append($input+'<style>.intrinsic-container{position:relative;overflow:hidden;min-height:400px;margin-bottom:10px}.intrinsic-container iframe{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;border:none}@media (max-width:990px){.intrinsic-container{min-height:1151px}}@media (max-width:510px){.intrinsic-container{min-height:1570px}}</style><div class="intrinsic-container"><iframe src="content.php" style="overflow: hidden;border:none;width:1000px;height:400px" scrolling="no""></iframe></div>').text()

    } else {

        $( '.afftextie' ).html("");

    }
}).change();
```

Comment: Please also post the code in the answer. Then it can get +1s

Comment: the iframe need to be in textarea and when clicked the style added

Comment: @Grasper, ebilgin has given you enough information for you to fix the problem exactly as you require. You may not have given enough information.

Comment: You cannot add a iframe in textarea. Textarea is a form control you can insert a text, not HTML. Secondly, adding css to iframe is another question you must ask. Please edit your question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ebilgin/wr39vhjt/3/ I'd edit the fiddle. I think its closer to your request.

Comment: @ebilgin, in my question I never mention an iframe. It's only in my code meant as a text for textarea..

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood your request. I think my last fiddle resolve your problem?